# Vertically align form element in a div using CSS

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

I am using jade to template my site. bellow is the jade template and css. I would like the form element to be centered inside of its parent div

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html 
    head 
        title #{title} - My Site 
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css') 
    body 
        .main-wrapper
            .header
                include main-header
            .main-container
                block contents
            .footer
                include main-footer
```

index.jade

```
extend layout
block contents
    form(action='/login', method='post')
        div
            |Username:
            input(id='username', type='text', value='', name='username')
        div
            |Password:
            input(id='password', type='password', value='', name='password')
        div
            input(type='submit', value='Login', data-transition='fade')
```

css

```
/*
 * Grab a custom font from Google
 */
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand");

html{
    height: 100%
}

body{
    height: 100%
}

.main-wrapper {
    height: 100%    
}

.header {
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fa5b4d;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.footer {
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fa5b4d;
}

.main-container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E47620;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

.main_container form{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

for some reason the form element is not centered inside its parent div, any ideas why?

Comment: If you can paste the outputted source code html, it would help a lot

Comment: A fiddle would be very helpful..

Comment: I think you can only use vertical-align for that on images. But you could use CSS tables.